# Is it necessary to use auth token in firebase and server

Tags: php, android, mysql, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an android app that uses phone authentication for authentication cloud firestore to store some data and mysql to store some other data. Now my problem is do I need to verify auth token id on php server? Since only authenticated users can only interact with the app hence the my mysql database

Comment: Which "auth token"? I'd read the documentation very carefully and look for recommendations, and follow those.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have data you don't want just anyone to get in your database, and that you expose that data through your PHP code, you most definitely will need to also check the auth token in your PHP code. The reason is that malicious users will try to access your PHP API without using your actual app. So if you don't check for a valid token and whether they are authorized, you'd be open to unlimited abuse.